# How to change default value of ANNIE resources in GATE from java code?

Tags: java, nlp, gate

In GATE default values for ANNIE is set during initialization but sometimes based on requirement it has to be changed.

**My Requirement** : I want to extract English sentences without considering "nextline character" but "full stop" which gives correct sentences. For that I need to change the default value of *transducerURL* in SentenceSplitter in ANNIE. 
This can be done in two ways :

1. Using *ANNIE_with_defaults.gapp* - changing initparams value in Sentencesplitter and accessing from java

   ```
       Gate.setGateHome(new File(Configuration.GATE_HOME));                        
       Gate.init();
       // Load ANNIE with defaults from the plug-ins folder
       File pluginsHome = Gate.getPluginsHome();
       File anniePlugin = new File(pluginsHome, ANNIEConstants.PLUGIN_DIR);
       File annieGapp = new File(anniePlugin, ANNIEConstants.DEFAULT_FILE);
       annieController = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(annieGapp);
   ```

**I am not being able to find where to change its value in gapp file.**

2. After initialising GATE, access ResourceData using CreoleRegister and change the default value of parameter *transducerURL* as shown below

   ```
   String resourceClassName = "gate.creole.splitter.SentenceSplitter";
           ResourceData resData = Gate.getCreoleRegister().get(resourceClassName);
           //System.out.println(resData.getParameterList());
           ParameterList params = resData.getParameterList();
           List<List<Parameter>> param =  params.getInitimeParameters();
           System.out.println(param);
           //System.out.println(param.get(0));
           for(List<Parameter> plist : param)
           {
               for(Parameter pm : plist)
               {
                   System.out.println("Name : "+pm.getName()+", "+pm.getDefaultValue());
               }
           }
   ```

**But Parameter does not have setDefaultvalue method.**

How to fix this?

**Any kind of help is welcome.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using *creole.xml*. I have tried with SentenceSplitter but it is giving me incorrect sentences. So, I am using RegexSentenceSplitter instead.
Added few lines in creole.xml-

```
<RESOURCE>
    <CLASS>gate.creole.splitter.RegexSentenceSplitter</CLASS>
    <PARAMETER NAME="externalSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/external-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom external-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER NAME="internalSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/internal-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom internal-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER NAME="nonSplitListURL" DEFAULT="file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/non-split-patterns.txt" COMMENT="The URL to the custom non-split-patterns.txt" SUFFIXES="txt;text">java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
</RESOURCE>
```

Then loading *ANNIE_with_defaults.gapp* from backend code as shown in the question.

**Hope it may be helpful.**